# cannot access local variable 'profile_form' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: django-forms

my html file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGmCA.png)

forms file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iztLz.png)

views file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh05f.png)

and I am getting error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSZkl.png)

Please, Anyone can help me to solve this.

I have given POST method in my form but it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to change **`profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()`** in `else` part.
- make form object **`profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()`** instead of **`profile = UserProfileInfoForm()`**

###### Your code become like this...

```py
def regisrer(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':

        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST)
        ...
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile = UserProfileInfoForm() # remove this
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm() # add this
    
    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html','user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed but i want know why it get error erliar because in IF statement i have mentioned it correctly, So it supposed to be exicute if block. why it came to else block. Please can you enlighten me ?